# Need to remove object from javascript by key

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {code: "sku", label: "SKU", value: "Number: 312312"}
1: {code: "show_more_options", label: "Show More Options", value: "New variant!"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

getting from variable order.attributes_list.

i need to remove from that element that has `code === "sku"`.

Comment: You have to iterate over the array of objects and skip the object which has code equal to sku. Did you give it a try?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.filter` for this with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to build a new array of wanted objects/items. Here, 
if the inner arrow function returns `true` the item (ie object) will be kept within the new array, if it returns false it wont be added.

```js
const arr = [{code: "sku", label: "SKU", value: "Number: 312312"},
{code: "show_more_options", label: "Show More Options", value: "New variant!"}];

const searchCode = "sku";
const res = arr.filter(({code}) => code !== searchCode);
console.log(res);
```